# HorizontalScrollView doesn't notify scale of child

Tags: android, scale, horizontalscrollview

I have the following problem:

I got a HorizontalScrollView, containing a LinearLayout "main". In this LinearLayout, I want to add several CustomViews. When I scale the LinearLayout "main" now, using scaleY and scale X, I want to be able to still scroll horizontally through the Layout (so it should be something like a zoom function). But the ScrollView doesn't realize that the width of "main" has changed. It stays in the old size. I've already tried several methods like requestLayout(), but nothing really works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the size of all children of "main" recursively. i.e.
put this right after scaleX()/scaleY():

```
    int mainWidth = (int) ((main.getWidth());
    for( i=0; i< main.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        childView = (View) main.getChildAt(i);
        childView.setWidth(mainWidth);
        childView.setHeight((int) (mainWidth*Weight));
    }
```

or if you just care about the ScrollView, put this code instead:

```
    int mainWidth = (int) ((main.getWidth());
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.YOURSCROLLVIEW);
    scrollView.setWidth(mainWidth);
    scrollView.setHeight((int) (mainWidth*Weight));
```

Comment: the children size is scaled correctly, scaleX()/scaleY() does it correct. Also, the width of main is larger then the width of the scrollview. This is the reason why I need a ScrollView. The size of the ScrollView should stay the same, but I want to be able to scroll till the end of "main" after I scaled it